# Make get request and copy data to server with PHP

Tags: php, get, cron, request

I want to use a cronjob to make a GET request every 60 minutes, to cache an RSS feed on my webserver. My hoster offers a web interface to create the cronjob, so that should be easy to do. As I have nearly no experience with php, I am struggeling with this part. My code currently looks like this:

```
<?php
$response = http_get("http://www.target-url.com/feed.rss");
$myfile = fopen("rp.xml", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
fwrite($myfile, $response);
?>
```

This writes alle the content to rp.xml, but it also writes the headers, so I get invalid xml. The content of rp.xml looks like this:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Wed, 28 Jan 2015 20:27:03 GMT
Content-Type: application/rss+xml;charset=utf-8
Connection: keep-alive
Set-Cookie: creid=1491575037291426898; expires=Thu, 31-Dec-37 23:55:55 GMT; domain=.target-url.com; path=/; httpOnly
X-Served-By-CC: s19lpay01
X-Cache-Control-Set-By: X-Set-Cache-TTL (300)
Cache-Control: public, max-age=300
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Last-Modified: Wed, 28 Jan 2015 20:23:16 GMT
Content-Length: 10672
Edge-Control: max-age=300
X-Cache: HIT (13)
X-Served-By: RFCTC01
Accept-Ranges: bytes
X-Age: 227

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rss xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" version="2.0">
{...rest of the xml}
```

Comment: What have you done to debug this? Try running it yourself from the CLI. Does it work then? If not - do a var_dump() on $response and $myfile to check that you actually fetch data from the remote server, and to check that you opened the file resource successfully. Also: you say that 'feed.rss' is not created. Would you expect that, if you try to write 'rp.xml'? I suppose this is just a typo.

Comment: Okay, now it works. But I only want the pure XML, not the headers. I edited my original question. How can I get rid of the headers automatically?

Comment: You could use file_get_contents() or curl.

Comment: file_get_contents() did the job. thanks @CamilStaps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [file_get_contents()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) instead:

```
string file_get_contents ( string $filename [, bool $use_include_path = false [, 
    resource $context [, int $offset = -1 [, int $maxlen ]]]] )
```

> file_get_contents() is the preferred way to read the contents of a file into a string. It will use memory mapping techniques if supported by your OS to enhance performance.
>
> Note: if you're opening a URI with special characters, such as spaces, you need to encode the URI with urlencode().